# In Node.js, are non-blocking constructs usually preferable to blocking ones?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

Is the following a statement of best practices in Node.js with regard to web applications? If not, how could it be improved?

**The statement**

The lifecycle of any web app has at least two phases: a setup phase, and a ready phase (when the   application is ready to respond to requests.)

In the ready phase,

1. IO operations (disk access, database calls, etc.) should always be asynchronous/non-blocking.
2. Even operations that occur purely in memory should be asynchronous. This is especially true when the operations involve iteration, and especially^2 true when the upper limit on the number of iterations is unknown.
3. Synchronous/blocking operations should never be performed in response to a request.

I do not believe this question is out-of-bounds for Stackoverflow. In my mind, the question of whether or not something is part of the best practices for developing in a certain programming language can be answered decisively based on experience and objective criteria.

Comment: How do you implement "2"? Separate process?

Comment: Quick example: suppose you're iterating over an array of strings. Each string is big and you're applying a regular expression to it, searching for a match.

You could use a for loop to iterate over the strings. As I understand Node, that for loop would block anything else happening in the application until it was finished.

Or you could iterate with callbacks/promises/etc. That would allow the application to do other work _between_ each operation on an item in the array.

Comment: I could be wrong, but my question was inspired by this: https://github.com/yortus/asyncawait/tree/master/comparison

Comment: So you are building your own time-slicing scheduler. Makes sense. Anyways, the answer is yes: In a multi-user system like a web server, you don't want to have one request block all others. Lacking multi-threads, you have to make sure you do all non-CPU work asynchronously, and time-slice long CPU tasks.

Comment: Thanks. In practice, of course, I'd use promises or the async library or something (or even a separate process in some cases.) But to some extent I was after the theoretical point here: however you do it, you don't block.

Comment: I would stray away from saying "always".  The answer of course is to use what is best for your application.  For **most** web applications, the non-blocking methods are best.  But remember, the flexibility of Node.js means that it can work well for strange edge cases where concurrency might not even be important.  If you are publishing this somewhere, I recommend not sticking to absolutes as people tend to read them and take them as fact no matter what they are building.

Comment: Good point. In my first draft of the statement, I didn't even limit it to web apps... and then remembered some of the command line programs I'd written in Node that didn't need to be asynchronous at all :-)

Comment: This question should probably be stated either at programmers.stackexchange.com or codereview.stackexchange.com